# screen -x ignore utf8

Tags: gnu-screen

I use screen and I use utf8 with this in my ~/.screenrc

```
# utf-8
encoding utf8 utf8
defencoding utf8
```

ok.
But, when I reopen screen with

```
screen -x
```

screen don't show the utf8 characters

## EDIT

I use OSX Terminal, but the problem is when I connect to ubuntu over ssh

my `locale` output

```
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=es_ES
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-U` flag to run `screen` in UTF-8 mode:

```
screen -U
screen -Ux
screen -Ur
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606570/os-x-terminal-utf-8-issues/

Answer (score 0):

What terminal program are you using? Does your terminal program support UTF-8 as well? In `Konsole`, you can check using `View > Set Encoding`. PuTTY has this as well in its settings.

Does your shell really output UTF-8? Check using `locale` command.

Answer (score 0):

According to your posted output of `locale`, the problem is that you have `$LC_ALL` set to "`C`", and this overrides all other settings with a generic, non-UTF8-capable locale.

Find out where `LC_ALL` is being set (likely `~/.*rc` or `~/.*profile`), and remove it – on *both* OS X and Ubuntu. Then log out and log in again.